# Объект ускоряется по неизвестной причине

Tags: javascript

Перемещаю объект нажатиями на клавиатуре, все элементарно просто, но почему-то объект начинает двигаться быстрее и быстрее, при том, что я его скорость не меняю. Чем дольше держу клавишу, тем быстрее персонаж двигается.
Уже все перепробовал

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

const WIDTH = 950;
const HEIGHT = 700;

var player = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
player.src = "img/player_right.png";
bg.src = "img/bg.png"; 

var xPos = WIDTH / 2 - 75;
var yPos = 550;
var delta = 0.1;

var keyA = 0;
var keyD = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.code == "KeyA")
    {
        keyA = 1;
        player.src = "img/player_left.png";
    }
    if (e.code == "KeyD")
    {
        keyD = 1;
        player.src = "img/player_right.png";
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.code == "KeyA")
    {
        keyA = 0;
    }
    if (e.code == "KeyD")
    {
        keyD = 0;
    }
});

function draw()
{
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); 
    ctx.drawImage(player, xPos, yPos, 50, 75);
    if (keyA == 1) 
    {
        xPos -= delta;
    }
    if (keyD == 1)
    {
        xPos += delta;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

player.onload = draw;
```

```css
body {
    background: rgb(205, 218, 200);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(184, 210, 182);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 13px;
    color: rgb(78, 59, 69);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#can {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(184, 210, 182);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 13px;
    color: rgb(78, 59, 69);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Money Rain </title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles.css"  />
        <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="img/Games.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "wrapper">
            <header>
                 Money Rain
            </header>
            <div id = "can">
                <canvas id = "canvas" width = "1100" height = "700"> </canvas>
            </div>
            <footer>
                    <span> Use keys A|D to move. Good luck! </span>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src = "index.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я тут первый раз, так что, надо ли картинки добавлять в вопрос (img игрока, фона и прочего) ?

Comment: если это ни как не помогает в понимании вопроса, то не нужно)

Answer (score 0):

*Could not reproduce.*

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

const WIDTH = 950;
const HEIGHT = 700;

var player = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
player.src = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png";
//"img/player_right.png";
bg.src = "img/bg.png";

var xPos = 0; //WIDTH / 2 - 75;
var yPos = 50; //550;
var delta = 0.1;

var keyA = 0;
var keyD = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.code == "KeyA") {
    keyA = 1;
    //player.src = "img/player_left.png";
  }
  if (e.code == "KeyD") {
    keyD = 1;
    //player.src = "img/player_right.png";
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.code == "KeyA") {
    keyA = 0;
  }
  if (e.code == "KeyD") {
    keyD = 0;
  }
});

function draw() {
  //ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); 
  ctx.drawImage(player, xPos, yPos, 150, 150);
  if (keyA == 1) {
    xPos -= delta;
  }
  if (keyD == 1) {
    xPos += delta;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  document.querySelector("header").textContent = (
    xPos.toFixed(2) + ", " + yPos.toFixed(2));
}

player.onload = draw;
draw();
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(205, 218, 200);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(184, 210, 182);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding: 13px;
  color: rgb(78, 59, 69);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#can {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border:1px solid black;
}

canvas {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:3px solid red;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(184, 210, 182);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding: 13px;
  color: rgb(78, 59, 69);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    Money Rain
  </header>
  <div id="can">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1100" height="700"> </canvas>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <span> Use keys A|D to move. Good luck! </span>
  </footer>
</div>
```